# How to implement a server for a python scripts testing system (with stdio)?

Tags: python, testing, backend, autotest

Could you advice how to implement server for scripts testing such as like on [coursera](https://coursera.org).

There is input, where students attach their script. 
And next steps are quite foggy for me as I see them:

1. server gets script
2. server checks extension of script
3. server runs bash script with testing data(std input), waits for result >> creates output file
4. output file is compared with solution
5. server sends response

Is it right? Are there any other solutions?

Comment: The hard part is the sandbox.  You also have to time out and kill slow scripts.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is from the local stackoverflow. I think that is enough to start from here: https://github.com/DMOJ/judge.